# Serious step-up current?

Tags: current, transformer

I have: 
(1 x 220V~550W/2.5A 50Hz induction generator),
(1 x 220V~176W/0.80A 50/60Hz step-up to 4000-0-4000V 20mA 20.000Hz dimmable, neon sign transformer)
and (1 x 220v~ step-down transformer from a defunct PC UPS)

I also have access to most of the general diodes, varistors and other electronic supplies needed to build any basic electrical/electronic system.

How would I go about increasing the **AMPERES** at the output while maintaining the V and Hz at 220V/50Hz

The system is planned for donation to a rural community so I have to use what is available and alter it, if possible, at the lowest possible cost.

Any assistance in the matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to build a welding machine by any chance?

Comment: It's Hydro-electric turbine

Comment: I would *love* to see a machine that could keep the voltage the same and gave more current. More power out than in would finally stick it to that pesky old 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Yea no canna cheat da laws of physics - *Scotty*

Comment: While you cannot do this within the ratings of the generator, it's a separate question from what physical properties those limits derive (thermal? mechanical? saturation?), what the safety factors there are and need to be, if there is any way to change the physical situation, etc.  For that matter, then generator may not even provide its rated output, or not do so beyond a certain duty cycle. A wiser course of action might be to look at demand management - ie, a system to automatically turn off the freezer while someone needs to use the power saw.

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the current at 220v by replacing the generator with a more powerful one.

You can increase the current with this generator by reducing the voltage.

You can increase the voltage by reducing the current.

You cannot magic more power out of thin air.

W=VxA

550W is all the generator has.

Comment: +1 - but..."magic more power out of thin air" http://powercastco.com/PDF/Power-Out-of-Thin-Air.pdf ;)

Comment: Nice, but that's not magicking it out of thin air - that's stealing power put into the air by other people.

Comment: I know ;) I was just having a bit of fun.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for you and for everyone, it is not possible to increase Wattage without extra input, regardless of what is used.

Power = Watts must be "conserved".
 ie you cannot increase available power with transformers or converters or any other equipment.
 Unfortunately.

Power = Volts x Amps.
Energy = Power x time

---

> I have: (1 x 220V~550W/2.5A 50Hz induction generator)

This is your energy source .
 (Energy = power x time.)

Power = V x I = 220 V x 2.5A = 550 Watts, as you say.

> (1 x 220V~176W/0.80A 50/60Hz step-up to 4000-0-4000V 20mA 20.000Hz dimmable, neon sign transformer)

This takes power and changes the voltage to current RATIO. The voltage x current product = power stays the same (or is slightly lower due to losses in the system.

220 v x 0.8A = 176 Watts (as you say).
 4000V x 20 ma x 2 windings = 160 Watts =  slightly less than input power.
 This could be intended to reflect the Watt lost in conversion or be due to rounding.
 eg I = Power/V = 176 Watts/8000 Volt = 22 mA = close enough to 20 mA.

> and (1 x 220v~ step-down transformer from a defunct PC UPS)

Again, a "ratio converter".

> How would I go about increasing the AMPERES at the output while maintaining the V and Hz at 220V/50Hz

To increase amperes while maintaining voltage you must increase V x I = increasing power = "something for nothing" = not doable.